# Jboss EAP 6.3 enable web.xml

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, jboss

When I deploy my app I get this warning:

```
[WARNING] Warning: selected war files include a WEB-INF/web.xml which will be ig
nored
(webxml attribute is missing from war task, or ignoreWebxml attribute is specifi
ed as 'true')
```

My web.xml is essential, here it is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app>
<security-constraint>
<web-resource-collection>
<web-resource-name>Secure Content</web-resource-name>
<url-pattern>/register.do</url-pattern>
</web-resource-collection>
<auth-constraint>
<role-name>admin</role-name>
</auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>

<login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>/loginform.html</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>/loginerror.html</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
    <realm-name>admin only</realm-name>
</login-config>
<security-role>
    <role-name>admin</role-name>
</security-role>
</web-app>
```

The deployment finishes succesfully, but whenever I try to use my login form I get redirected to the "resource not available" page.

I even added

```
<webXml>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml</webXml>
```

to pom.xml `<properties>`

Extract of my pom:

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>${version.war.plugin}</version>
  <configuration>
    <!-- Java EE 6 doesn't require web.xml, Maven needs to catch up! -->
    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
    <webXml>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml</webXml>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: What is the configuration of your `maven-war-plugin` in your pom file?

Comment: @assylias this is what it is now: `<plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${version.war.plugin}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- Java EE 6 doesn't require web.xml, Maven needs to
                        catch up! -->
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                    <webXml>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml</webXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>`

Comment: You should remove the `<failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>` since you are providing one. You will then see if maven finds your web.xml file - if it doesn't the build will fail and you will probably need to amend the path given in your pom so that maven can find the file.